# Difference between volatitlity of Annualized return and Annualized volatility of returns

Tags: variance, descriptive-statistics

I have a series of monthly returns on financial data.  My goal is to estimate the volatility of 10 year rolling returns.  I am a bit confused on two options.

a) Calculate 10 year rolling returns, annualize this and then calculate the volatility of the annualized series

b)  Calculate 10 year rolling returns, find the volatility of this series, and then annualize the volatility.

I would be grateful for any insights.

Comment: I see two close votes, one as "off-topic" and one as "self-study". I don't think any of the two is fair. The understanding of variance of a time series and overlapping observations seems on topic to me. Also, it is not clear this is a homework question. Whoever votes to close as "self-study" could in addition warn the OP to add the relevant tag. That was my two pence.

Comment: My concern here would be that you're finding the volatility of overlapping data, assuming rolling returns means the return for years 1-10, then the return for years 2-11, then the return for years 3-12, etc. I'm not sure it's reasonable to take volatilitys in the situation.

Comment: Thanks Richard, this is not a homework question, i am using this medium for the first time, any ideas how i could add relevant tags?

Comment: Thank you barrycarter, is there any reason why overlapping returns couldn't be used in this case? And suppose i have non overlapping but shorter series - 1-3, 4-6, etc I am still not sure if i should annualize the series and find the volatility of the annualized series - or calculate the volatility of the series and annualize that

Comment: If you look at years 1-10 as one data point and years 2-11 as the next data point, you have an overlap of 9 years (years 2-10). Since year 2-10 data is the same for both data points, you're not really measuring the "full" volatility; in some sense, you're just measuring 2 years worth of volatility and treating it like 10 years worth.